# Create pydantic model for json schema having "oneOf" reference

Tags: python, jsonschema, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to convert an existing json schema into pydantic model (for fastapi proj) using "datamodel-code-genertor" (https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/datamodel_code_generator/). But it is failing. I tried to simulate the issue with following schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "Person",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "title": "name",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "pet": {
            "title": "pet",
            "type": "object",
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Pets/Cat"
                },
                {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Pets/Dog"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "Pets": {
            "Cat": {
                "title": "Cat",
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "type",
                    "hunts",
                    "age"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "pet_type": {
                        "enum": [
                            "Cat"
                        ]
                    },
                    "hunts": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "age": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Dog": {
                "title": "Dog",
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "type",
                    "bark",
                    "breed"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "pet_type": {
                        "enum": [
                            "Dog"
                        ]
                    },
                    "bark": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "breed": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
C:\schema\refactored_schema>datamodel-codegen --input pets_modifiled_question_working.json --input-file-type=jsonschema --output pets_modifiled_question_working.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sonali.ingale\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\datamodel_code_generator\__main__.py", line 281, in main
    generate(
  File "c:\users\sonali.ingale\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\datamodel_code_generator\__init__.py", line 259, in generate
    results = parser.parse()
  File "c:\users\sonali.ingale\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\datamodel_code_generator\parser\base.py", line 332, in parse
    _, sorted_data_models, require_update_action_models = sort_data_models(
  File "c:\users\sonali.ingale\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\datamodel_code_generator\parser\base.py", line 110, in sort_data_models
    return sort_data_models(
  File "c:\users\sonali.ingale\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\datamodel_code_generator\parser\base.py", line 110, in sort_data_models
    return sort_data_models(
  File "c:\users\sonali.ingale\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\datamodel_code_generator\parser\base.py", line 110, in sort_data_models
    return sort_data_models(
  [Previous line repeated 97 more times]
  File "c:\users\sonali.ingale\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\datamodel_code_generator\parser\base.py", line 158, in sort_data_models
    raise Exception(f'A Parser can not resolve classes: {unresolved_classes}.')
Exception: A Parser can not resolve classes: [class: Person references: {'Dog', 'Cat'}]
```

Currently my $ref json pointer is pointing to "#/definitions/Pets/Cat". If I do not encapsulate the "Cat" and "Dog" in "Pets" and use the json pointer as "#/definitions/Cat" it works. But I need that encapsulation as the original schema is very large and complex. It will be great if someone can help. Thanks.

.

Comment: You should submit a bug report to the json schema implementation you are using.